# Cuda out of memory in multiclass classification with PyTorch

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have 32Gb of GPU and facing the problem of “Cuda out of memory.”
I tried to improve my train routine:

```
import gc
def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    epoch_acc = 0.0
    
    model.train()
    
    for batch in iterator:
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        predictions = model(batch.posts) 
        
        loss = criterion(predictions, batch.type_numeric.long().to(device))
        
        acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.type_numeric.long().to(device))
        
        loss.backward()
        
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()
        #####################
        #the following part really slows the code execution
        del predictions
        del loss
        del acc
        del batch
        gc.collect()
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        #####################
    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

and also, I lowered the batch size to have small values:

```
train_batch_size      =   4
valid_batch_size      =   4
test_batch_size       =   4
```

but still, I get the error Cuda out of memory:

[image]

The problem even exists with the batch of 1. My task is an NLP multiclass classification task on a dataset that has, after preprocessing, 1 Gb. I tried to reduce MAX_VOCAB_SIZE to 300. I use the CNN model with the parameters:

```
INPUT_DIM = len(TEXT.vocab)
EMBEDDING_DIM = 300
N_FILTERS = 100
FILTER_SIZES = [2,3,4]
OUTPUT_DIM = len(LABEL.vocab)
DROPOUT = 0.2
PAD_IDX = TEXT.vocab.stoi[TEXT.pad_token]

model = CNN(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM, N_FILTERS, FILTER_SIZES, OUTPUT_DIM, DROPOUT, PAD_IDX)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

criterion1 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model = model.to(device)
criterion1 = criterion1.to(device)
```

My model has the following structure:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, n_filters, filter_sizes, output_dim, 
                 dropout, pad_idx):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        
        self.convs = nn.ModuleList([
                                    nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1, 
                                              out_channels = n_filters, 
                                              kernel_size = (fs, embedding_dim)) 
                                    for fs in filter_sizes
                                    ])
        
        self.fc = nn.Linear(len(filter_sizes) * n_filters, output_dim)
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, text):
        
        text = text.permute(1, 0)
                
        embedded = self.embedding(text)
                
        embedded = embedded.unsqueeze(1)
        
        conved = [F.relu(conv(embedded)).squeeze(3) for conv in self.convs]
            
        pooled = [F.max_pool1d(conv, conv.shape[2]).squeeze(2) for conv in conved]
  
        cat = self.dropout(torch.cat(pooled, dim = 1)) 
        return self.fc(cat)
```

The model has 365,716 trainable parameters (in a ‘reduced’ version of MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 300 instead of 25000 and batch sizes of 4, instead of 256/64/64). The OOM happens on the first iteration. The problem does not exist with the same model on the small dataset (70MB)

Also, for text vocabulary I use:

```
TEXT.build_vocab(train_ds, 
                 min_freq   =  3,
                 max_size   =  MAX_VOCAB_SIZE,
                 vectors    = 'fasttext.en.300d',
                 unk_init   =  torch.Tensor.normal_
                 )
```

What would you suggest for solving this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try 16 bit precision or CPU-offloading with [deepspeed](https://www.deepspeed.ai/tutorials/zero-offload/) library.

Comment: You can use `batch.type_numeric.short()` instead of `batch.type_numeric.long()`?

Comment: @ndrwnaguib thank you. I can't use short() because of the CrossEntropy loss - it asks for a long().

Comment: @Kevin thanks - please, where would you use 16 bit precision?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem appears at the line :
```
conved = [F.relu(conv(embedded)).squeeze(3) for conv in self.convs
```